# How to organize lists in list alphabetically?

Tags: python, list

I have a couple of list in a list sorted like this:

```
L = [['b','4'].['a','7'],['c','2']]
```

I want to see if it is possible to arrange the list so that it looks bit like this:

```
L = [['a','7'],['b','4'],['c','2']]
```

The first character of each list is placed alphabetically. How might I go about doing this?

Comment: In this case, literally just `sorted(L)` gets the job done

Comment: Do you guys think this is overkill? `print(sorted(L, key=operator.itemgetter(0)))`

Comment: It's overkill in the sense that you don't need a `key` function to do what you want.

Comment: Alright thank you guys. I am just gonna use a simple L.sort()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.sort()` that will sort the list alphabetically

```
L = [['b','4'],['a','7'],['c','2']]
L.sort()

output: [['a', '7'], ['b', '4'], ['c', '2']]
```

Answer (score 2):

use method  `sorted()`:

```
L = [['b','4'], ['a', '7'],['c','2']]
print(sorted(L))  # output [['a', '7'], ['b', '4'], ['c', '2']]
```